# Simple query about the apache Include directive

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, deny

I understand the principle of including external files into the `httpd.conf` using the `Include` directive, but I just want to double-check that I've understood how it works.

On our server, we already include a bunch of configuration files using something like

```
Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
```

Now I also have a bunch of IP addresses that I know I'm going to need to specify more than once (for restricted access).

At the moment I have:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/foo">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    # IP block 1
    Allow from 1.1.1.1
    Allow from 1.2.3.4
    # IP block 2
    Allow from 2.3.4.5
    Allow from 7.8.9.10
</Directory>
```

etc

Can I put all those `Allow` statements into an external file so that it reads something like:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/foo">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Include /path/to/iplist.conf
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/bar">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Include /path/to/iplist.conf
    # Some extra addresses for this directory
    Allow from 11.12.13.14
    Allow from 20.21.22.23
</Directory>
```

where `iplist.conf` just contains

```
# IP block 1
Allow from 1.1.1.1
Allow from 1.2.3.4
# IP block 2
Allow from 2.3.4.5
Allow from 7.8.9.10
```

Does that make sense? There isn't any reason that the `Include` directive should barf over something like this, is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `Include` directive works exactly as you think and there's no problem to use it in order to allow certain IP addresses or networks.

Just make sure that your file is **NOT** in the */etc/httpd/conf.d* directory, or it will get included by default in the main *httpd.conf* file and that may lead to odd results. On a side note, if you use wildcards to include your files, keep in mind that they will be loaded in alphabetical order.

Comment: I've put the file in question in `/etc/httpd/conf/`, rather than `/etc/httpd/conf.d`, but it's named `allowed_IPs.txt`, so wouldn't have been hit by our wildcard include (which looks for `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf`). Thank you, this is working precisely as expected.